# Как добавить отспут в этом месте?

Tags: opencart

Подскажите, как задать в стилях правильный путь конкретно для этой ссылке? Нужно не много добавить отступов. Через инспектора получается так сделать(обвёл красным цветом, что через браузер добавил), но в самом шаблоне такого пути разумеется нет.

**Движок:** OpenCart 2.3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1){
margin-left: нужное_кол-во_пикселей;
}
```